# Probabilistic model to approach problem that is usually dealt with linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, probability, numerical-modelling

I have the following problem. Let's say we have $x_{jk}$ it is an expression value of gene $j$ in a sample $k$. It is the average of expression levels across the cell types $s_{ij}$, weighted by respective proportions $a_{ki}$ ($i = 1 \cdots N$, $N$ is the disease type):

$$
x_{jk} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_{ki}s_{ij}
$$

Generally this can be expressed as matrix form

$$
 X = AS
$$

What I want to do is to solve this equation

\begin{align}
&\min_{A}\ || AS- X||^{2}\\
&\text{subject to } \left\{
\begin{array}{c l}      
    \sum_{i} a_{ki} = 1\\
    a_{ki} \ge0, \forall i
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

Typically this is solved by using quadratic programming.  The  number of genes is  large (e.g. ~30K).

I'm wandering if there is any good probabilistic model to deal such kind of problem?

Comment: I cannot provide an answer, but your problem sounds like it may be [Convex non-negative matrix factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization#Convex_non-negative_matrix_factorization). If so, you might try searching on that term, or putting it in your question title and/or description.

Comment: @GeoMatt22: Note quite. In NMF **both** *A* and *S* is unknown. In my problem *A* is known.

Comment: You mean S is known? (A is the argument of the objective function)

Comment: @GeoMatt22: Oops you're right. *S* is known.